# First variation on Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

The first variation of function $f(t)$ on interval $[0,T]$ is defined as

$$ FV(f) = \lim_{\|\pi\| \rightarrow 0} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f( t_{i+1} ) - f( t_i)|.$$

How can we estimate the first variation of Brownian Motion?

I set $Q_{\pi} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |f( t_{i+1} ) - f( t_i)|$. And compute that $\mathbf{E}[Q_{\pi}] = 0$ and $\mathbf{Var}[Q_{\pi}] = T$, based on these results, how can we compute $\lim_{||\pi|| \rightarrow 0} Q_{\pi}$ ? Is it $\sqrt{T}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the quadratic variation of Brownian motion up to time $t$ is simply given by $t$. It follows that the first variation of Brownian motion is infinite since processes of finite first variation have $0$ quadratic variation.

Indeed, if $X$ is a continuous process with finite first variation then for any partition $\mathcal{P}$,
\begin{align*}\sum_\mathcal{P} |X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i)|^2 &\leq \max_\mathcal{P} |X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i)| \cdot \sum_\mathcal{P} |X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i)| \\& \leq \max_{|s-t| \leq \|\mathcal{P}\|} |X(t) - X(s)| \cdot FV(X) \to 0
\end{align*}
as $\|\mathcal{P}\| \to 0$ since $X$ is continuous.

Comment: why can we have the second inequality?

Comment: If $s \in (t_i, t_{i+1})$ then $|X(t_i) - X(t_{i+1})| \leq |X(t_i) - X(s)| + |X(s) - X(t_{i+1})|$ by the triangle inequality. In particular, the limit defining the finite variation is the limit of an increasing the sequence (refining the partition only makes the sum larger). Hence we can bound $\sum_{\mathcal{P}} |X(t_{i+1}) - X(t_i)| \leq FV(X)$.

Comment: @RhysSteele a humble request for clarification: the above shows that under the assumption for contradiction, the quadratic variation converges to $0$ almost surely(?). However, we know that "the quadratic variation of Brownian motion up to time $t$ is simply given by $t$" only in the sense of $L^2$ convergence and not a.s. convergence. (Remark 15.6 https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/first_properties.pdf). Where exactly does our contradiction come from?

Comment: @user35443 Suppose for a contradiction that $\mathbb{P}(FV(B)< \infty) > 0$. From the answer, if $\omega \in \Omega$ and $FV(B(\omega))< \infty$ then for any sequence of partitions $P_i$ with $\|P_i\| \to 0$, we have that $\lim_{i \to \infty} \sum_{P_i} |B_{t_i}(\omega) - B_{t_{i+1}}(\omega)|^2 = 0$. Also for any such sequence of partitions, $\lim_{i \to \infty} \sum_{P_i} |B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i+1}}|^2 = t$ in the $L^2(\Omega)$-sense and hence along a subsequence almost surely. Hence that subsequence converges to $0$ a.e. and to $t$ with positive probability which is a contradiction.